# Finding generating function and coefficient with symbolic method and Lagrange

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, trees, analytic-combinatorics, lagrange-inversion

I would appreciate any help on the following two problem:

Given the symbolic equation $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{Q}^{[\ast]}$
and $\mathcal{Q}=Δ∗\mathcal{T}∗\mathcal{T}$, I am trying to build the exponential generating functions corresponding to these equations (as described, for example, in the book "Analytic Combinatorics" http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) and read $T_n$ as the coefficient $n![z^n]$ of the generating function.

As far as I've understood it, the equations should correspond with (T(z), Q(z) denoting the exponential generating function):

$Q(z)=z⋅T(z)⋅T(z)$
and $T(z)=exp(Q(z))$

Now I'm trying to apply the Lagrange–Bürmann formula. So I've expressed z as $z=\frac{log(T)}{T^2}$=:$\frac{x}{Φ(x)}$
and do $[z^n]T(z)$=$[z^n]f(log(T))$=$\frac{1}{n}[x^{n−1}]f′(x)(\Phi(x))^n$ = ... = $\frac{1}{n}[x^n](\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!})^{2n−2}$

Since I see no way, to read the coefficient now, I guess I've probably been mistaken somewhere. Does anyone find my mistake?

Comment: Is unclear what the Lagrange-Bürmann-formula is or why does no one seem to know the answer to my question?

Comment: I think the problem is that I haven't chosen f(x) in the correct way... Does anyone know what f(x) does look like here given f(z) = T(z)?